# VMC cannot detect application type when publishing Play Framework 2.2 app to CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, playframework-2.2

I am using a free cloud foundry account. Today I tried pushing my Play 2.2 application but it  rejects to start, the message is `Unable to detect a supported application type (RuntimeError)`.

Deploying the app to cloud foundry is done as described in [the official documentation.](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Deploying-CloudFoundry)

Has anyone yet get this working?

Here is the full error message:

```
Preparing to start ***... OK
-----> Downloaded app package (38M)
/var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:94:in `build_pack': Unable to detect a supported application type (RuntimeError)
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:72:in `block in compile_with_timeout'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:71:in `compile_with_timeout'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:53:in `block in stage_application'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:49:in `chdir'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/lib/buildpack.rb:49:in `stage_application'
from /var/vcap/packages/dea_next/buildpacks/bin/run:10:in `<main>'
Checking status of app '***'...Application failed to stage
```

---

EDIT: I posted the issue on the official mailing list. No answer yet. But here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. create a new play 2.2 app ( `play new version22` )
2. cd into app directory ( `cd version22` )
3. build the project ( `play dist` )
4. push the application to cloud foundry ( `cf push --path=target/universal/version22-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` ) -- just chose the defaults
5. *bang*

I guess this is caused by the [new Feature (What's new in Play 2.2?)](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22) **New stage and dist tasks** that changed the packaging of the app. This could cause cloud foundry problem to detect the application type.

Comment: Stumbled on the same issue in play 2.2.0 and any cloud foundry variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [confirmed as a bug](https://twitter.com/thisismana/status/387562505746124800). Should be fixed soon.

Comment: Play 2.2 support in the Cloud Foundry Java buildpack was fixed at the end of October: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/commit/4db158aaf2c0ca2a1540c120b0d74381b42c47f0.

Answer (score 0):

Which cloud foundry version are you targeting on v1 or v2?

Error which you are encountering is because , cf is not having a build pack for play framework.

If you are targeting cloud foundry v2 try pushing application this way:

cf push --buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack

Comment: Seems to be an issue that only appears with play 2.2. I ported the app to 2.1.5 and 2.0.8. Works like a charme

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I got it working using the following `manifest.yml` to deploy on cloud foundry v2:

```
---
env:
  JAVA_HOME: .java
applications:
- name: <APP_NAME>
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  host: <AP_HOST_NAME>
  domain: cfapps.io
  path: <PATH_TO_ZIP_FILE>
  command: ./<DIR_PACKAGE_NAME>/bin/<APP_NAME>
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
```

You have to fill in the info between <> for your app, and config other information as well, but the core solution is to provide the `JAVA_HOME` env variable, and the correct path to the start command.

Perhaps we should consider a SBT task to create this file as a permanent fix, or maybe update the java-buildpack... I'm not sure which one is the best approach.

**Edit**: You also will need to place a script called start in `<DIR_PACKAGE_NAME>/start`, or else cloud foundry will try to compile the app and fail miserably - I suppose this needs to be fixed in java-buildpack as well.